# ValueError: Invalid version (was 41, expected 1 to 40)

Tags: python, flask, qr-code

I'm trying to make a Flask app which generates a qr code for a image. My code looks fine but im still facing an error: ValueError: Invalid version (was 41, expected 1 to 40).
In the browser I got:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
  File AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 160, in make
    self.best_fit(start=self.version)
  File AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 232, in best_fit
    self.version = bisect_left(
  File AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 115, in version
    util.check_version(value)
  File AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\qrcode\util.py", line 185, in check_version
 raise ValueError(f"Invalid version (was {version}, expected 1 to 40)")
ValueError: Invalid version (was 41, expected 1 to 40)
```

What are the possible ways to solve the problem?

Python:

```
def generate_qr_image(data):
    memory = BytesIO()

     qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1,
                   error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
                   box_size=10, border=4)
     qr.add_data(data)
     qr.make(fit=True)

     img = qr.make_image(fill_color='white', back_color='#282d39')
     img = img.convert("RGBA")

     background = Image.new("RGBA", img.size)
     qr_code = Image.alpha_composite(background, img)
     qr_code.save(memory, format="PNG")
     memory.seek(0)

     base64_img = "data:image/png;base64," + \
        b64encode(memory.getvalue()).decode('ascii')

     return base64_img


@app.route('/qr_image_select', methods=['POST'])
def image_select():
 if 'image-input' in request.files:
    image_file = request.files['image-input']  
    if image_file:
        image_data = image_file.read()
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('ascii')
        qr_image_data = generate_qr_image(encoded_string)
        return render_template('qr_image.html', data=qr_image_data)

return "No image file selected."
```

HTML:

```
   <form action="/qr_image_select" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image-input">
        <button type="submit" class="button">Select File</button>
   </form>
   <br><br>

   {% if data %}
   <div class="qrcode">
      <img src="{{ data }}" alt="QR_CODE">
      <p>qr_code has been generated!</p>
   </div>
   {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error traceback

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/issues/331) it happens when you try to put too much data into your qrcode.

Comment: I tried to generate qr code for low resolution picture. Still nothing.

Comment: How low resolution are we talking? Binary data has to be smaller than 2953 bytes to fit into a QR code with error correction level L according to Wikipedia. It's an inherent limitation of the QR code format.